# Question regarding minimization and orthogonality

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable mapping with $f'(t)\neq\textbf{0}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $\textbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a point not in $f(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> (a) Show there is a point $\textbf{q}=f(t)$ on the curve $f(\mathbb{R})$ $\textit{closest}$ to $\textbf{p}$.
>
> (b) Show that the vector $r=(\textbf{p}-\textbf{q})$ is orthogonal to the curve at $\textbf{q}$. $\textbf{Hint: }$Consider the function $t\mapsto|\textbf{p}-f(t)|$ and its derivative.

I'm not sure how to approach this. It appears to be a least squares problem. The hint on (b) seems to imply that the derivative of the distance formula is $0$ at $\textbf{q}$, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: For part (a), consider the function $t \mapsto \operatorname{dist}(f(t), p)$.  This is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued function of a single variable.  Is it continuously differentiable?  If so, can you use any results about $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions of a single variable to prove the result?  Something about finding minima and maxima on compact sets?  For part (b), consider [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $$ p = (0,0) $$ and 
$$ f(t) = \left( \; e^{-t} \cos t , \; e^{-t} \sin t \;  \right)  $$

Comment: Could you elaborate on why there isn't a value of $t$ for which $f(t)$ is closest to $p$?